# Read contents of Initialization range and SegmentBase indexRange in a DASH stream

Tags: html, webm, mpeg-dash

I have been trying to understand how DASH works, mainly the MPD and how a remote client boots-up to play a stream. Of many parameters in the MPD, the Initialization range and SegmentBase indexRange seems to be of much interest. If I understand it right, these values give the base URL and the mappings to key-frames that must be retrieved if the client seeks/rewinds a video.

My question is if these values can be seen before I actually play a video. For example, can I use a tool like youtube-dl to download these byte-ranges and decode them in a way that is human readable?

Much appreciated.
-Jamie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm also starting to look into `DASH` so take my answer with a grain of salt.

The `SegmentBase` is used when you have a *single* segment in a representation. For multiple segments there's `SegmentList` and `SegmentTemplate`. You can find more in this [MPEG-DASH overview](https://www.bitcodin.com/blog/2015/04/mpeg-dash/).

For MPEG-DASH the `SegmentBase` `indexRange` attribute points to the location of the `sidx` box ([Segment Index Box](https://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/2012/02/01/dash-support/)). The box contains information about the sub-segments and random access points for seeking etc. There's more info in this [Quick Tutorial on MPEG-DASH](https://arashafiei.wordpress.com/2012/11/13/quick-dash/).

In the case of WebM-DASH the segment index corresponds to the [Cues element](http://wiki.webmproject.org/adaptive-streaming/webm-dash-specification).

The `Initialization` `range` attribute points to the initialization segment.

If the server supports it you could issue HTTP Range requests to get the data but you'll need to parse it.

There's a Node.js ISO BMFF parser here: [iso-bmff-parser-stream](https://github.com/necccc/iso-bmff-parser-stream) and the DASH-IF reference client implementation in JavaScript can be found at: [dash.js](https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js/).

For WebM the `Cues` can be read using [mkvinfo](https://www.bunkus.org/videotools/mkvtoolnix/doc/mkvinfo.html), as reported by @jamie.

Comment: Thanks for the information aergistal. I will check these out in more detail.

Comment: Hi again, I have tried to use the ISO BMFF parser and it seems to work great for the two files which comes with the package. However, it does not seem to work with my .mp4 files. It throws a `FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_0 Allocation failed - process out of memory` error. Also does the same recommendation apply to a .webm file. Ideally I would like to see the `sidx` box for both mp4 and webm files. Any ideas on this?

Comment: May be a bug in the parser, haven't tried it yet. For `WebM` the Segment Index corresponds to the `Cues` element. See: http://wiki.webmproject.org/adaptive-streaming/webm-dash-specification

Comment: Great stuff. Seems that the cues can be read using the `mkvinfo` tool.

Comment: Yes. The server supports HTTP Range requests, how can I parse it ?